# Docker: uwsgi not starting

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, uwsgi

When I start my uwsgi from inside the docker container everything works fine.
I call:

```
docker run -it -p 9098:9098 --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash pyramid:latest
```

Inside the container I call:

```
jenkins@9c36ddb99971:~/my_project$ uwsgi --ini-paste dev.ini --chdir /home/jenkins/my_project/
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from dev.ini
jenkins@9c36ddb99971:~/my_project
```

and everything is running correctly.

```
docker ps -a
9c36ddb99971        pyramid:latest      "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Up About a minute           0.0.0.0:9098->9098/tcp   festive_ride
```

When I try to start the uwsgi service from outside, uwsgi is not running

```
me@me-W35 ~/docker_test/pyramid $ docker run -it -p 9098:9098 --rm pyramid:latest
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/jenkins/my_project/dev.ini
me@me-W35 ~/docker_test/pyramid
```

I tried ENTRYPOINT, CMD, RUN...nothing worked. Nothing happens. No errors.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libffi-dev && \
    apt-get install -y vim && \
    apt-get install -y iputils-ping && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libxmlsec1-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev

RUN useradd -m jenkins
USER jenkins
ENV HOME /home/jenkins

# Install Python 2.7.11
RUN curl -o $HOME/Python-2.7.11.tar.xz  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tar.xz && \
    tar -xf $HOME/Python-2.7.11.tar.xz -C $HOME && \
    cd $HOME/Python-2.7.11 && ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/python2711 && make && make install

COPY requirements.txt $HOME/

USER jenkins

# Install pip
RUN curl -s https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > /tmp/get-pip.py && \
    $HOME/local/python2711/bin/python2.7 /tmp/get-pip.py && \
    $HOME/local/python2711/bin/pip install virtualenv

RUN $HOME/local/python2711/bin/virtualenv $HOME/my_project
WORKDIR $HOME/my_project
RUN . $HOME/my_project/bin/activate;

RUN $HOME/local/python2711/bin/pip install -r $HOME/requirements.txt

ENV PATH $HOME/local/python2711/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH $HOME/local/python2711/lib

COPY dev.ini $HOME/my_project/
USER root
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins $HOME/
USER jenkins

EXPOSE 9098
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini-paste", "/home/jenkins/my_project/dev.ini", "--chdir", "/home/jenkins/my_project"]
```

dev.ini:

```
###

# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:my_package

pyramid.reload_templates = false
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, my_package

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console

[logger_my_package]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = my_package

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 9099

[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:9098
socket = :9097
master = true
module = my_package:application
processes = 4
harakiri = 3600
harakiri-verbose = true
limit-post = 65536
post-buffering = 8192
#logto = /home/jenkins/my_package.log
daemonize = /home/jenkins/my_package.log
pidfile = /home/jenkins/my_package.pid
stats = /home/jenkins/my_packagestats
listen = 128
max-requests = 1000
reload-on-as = 128
reload-on-rss = 96
no-orphans = true
log-slow = true
need-app = true
memory-report = true
```

Comment: `docker logs your_container` should show a few things

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Trying to build your Dockerfile i crashes because I don't have the files you use in COPY commands (requirements.txt and dev.ini)

Comment: I have no container to log...docker ps -a is empty

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis: I copy some other files (from bitbucket) in the docker container. I can't provide them here. I added the dev.ini above

Comment: Ok, now i put dev.ini and commented the COPY requirements.txt . Will see if it works and if I'm able to reproduce the problem. I'll back to you with results and an answer

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. uwsgi command is not present on system (on container), so I guess is installed in someway using requirements.txt which I don't have.

Comment: You are right. uwsgi is installed via requirements.txt. But unfortunately the application will not start without the packages from bitbucket....I can't provide these files here sorry.

Comment: No problem. I'm able to reproduce the problem. Finally I added `RUN pip install uwsgi` to Dockerfile and now I have the environment with the same problem. I'm investigating.

Comment: I think the problem is not related to docker, is uwsgi related. I'm not sure to be able to reproduce the problem exactly because if I run the container with a bash shell, manually launching on the container `uwsgi --ini-paste dev.ini --chdir /home/jenkins/my_project/` it responds `[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from dev.ini` but after that if I look for the process `ps -aux`, I can't see anything related to uwsgi. So the command is terminating... that's the reason of the problem. The container doesn't remain because it finished its execution. But the CMD is executing ok.

Comment: I tried also "-d" option to daemonize the uwsgi... but it finish instantly too. I can't reach any website on my host at port 9098 in any case... If you do, you are one step forward me. Probably because some configuration regarding requirements.txt. I can't do more... I only can assure you that the CMD command is executing ok and I'm getting same result with CMD as launching it manually from bash shell inside the container. Sorry :/

Comment: Thx. for your investigation. I presume too that the uwsgi configuration is the problem. If I found the solution, I will post it here...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the dev.ini I have to change the "uncomments" like this:

```
logto = /home/jenkins/my_package.log
#daemonize = /home/jenkins/my_package.log
```

In Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi"]
CMD ["--ini-paste", "/home/jenkins/my_project/dev.ini", "--chdir", "/home/jenkins/my_project"]
```

Now the uwsgi is starting correctly.